# How do i add extra dimensions to a screenshot?

Tags: python, sikuli

I currently have the code below.. and it takes the screenshot just fine.. but it cuts off the left and right side of the screenshot

How do i add another 10 pixels all around possible?

```
print "Taking SS..."    
focusWindow = App.focusedWindow()
regionINFO = capture(App.focusedWindow())
shutil.move(regionINFO, os.path.join(r'C:\Screenshots', 'Dummy1.png'))
print "SS Done..."
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're taking a screenshot of a specific app. Try the whole screen.

```
import shutil # once at beginning of script
img = capture(SCREEN)
shutil.move(img, 'path')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is present within your code itself. :)

```
focusWindow = App.focusedWindow()
```

Here, focusWindow stores the region of the App which the focus is upon. Either like Eugene has said above, you can go ahead to take the whole screenshot or you can append to the current of focusWindow and capture the region.

For eg.: Say you want to add 10 pixels on all sides, it would be like:

```
focusWindow.x -= 10
focusWindow.y -= 10
focusWindow.w += 20
focusWindow.h += 20
regionINFO = capture(focusWindow)
shutil.move(regionINFO, os.path.join(r'C:\Screenshots', 'Dummy1.png'))
print "SS Done..."
```